# Open socket connection from backend to client running on a different machine in socket.io Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, express, socket.io

I have a Node application that should run the frontend on one Docker container and the backend on another one. Both the frontend and backend are using Express.

Before this application was running on a single machine and I was using a socket connection to communicate with the client ([sockect.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io))

But now I will have two different machines so I was wondering about the best strategy to establish a socket connection between the backend and the frontend.
The reason is that in the backend I will have access to all the DBs with all the info so it should be able to send these info to the client every time that a specific condition happens.
The problem is that at the moment I'm using a proxy in the frontend to route all the client requests to the backend so the backend is 'hidden' to the client and I'm not sure how to open the socket connection.
I was wondering if the best strategy would be to NOT use the proxy and instead allow CORS on the backend so that the client can directly communicate with it and open the socket connection.
What are the advantages and disadvantages here? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is less of a question about tech, as it is about deployment. What I'm understanding here is that you're trying to run your socket.io based services as a different process on a different machine.

Cheapest and easiest way would be to have the frontend connect its socket to a different subdomain. You can achieve this by adding another A record to your DNS entry. [[steps]](https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238)

If you're anyways deploying behind NGINX you can try reverse proxying the socket endpoint. [[steps]](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

I'd recommend my first idea, it's usually the easiest.